# How to get text label appearing in MATLAB in Computer Vision Toolbox

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, imaging, matlab-cvst

So I have just started using Computer Vision toolbox in MATLAB and I have been trying to track blobs in a video.

So I am able to output the number of blobs being detected and have a bounding box around the detected blob.

Now I am trying to have the labels showing up on the image. So basically just like the bounding box is showing up, I want the labels (small numbers 1, 2, 3 etc.) to show up.

Any idea on how this can be done?

This is my code so far:

```
blobAnalysis = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
    'AreaOutputPort', false, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
    'MinimumBlobArea', 0,'LabelMatrixOutputPort', true);

while ~isDone (videoReader)
    videoFrame = step(videoReader);
    foreground = step (foregroundDetector, videoFrame);
    cleanForeground = imopen(foreground, strel('Disk',1));

    [centroids, bbox, Label] = step (blobAnalysis, cleanForeground);

    Label;
    centroids

    result = insertShape(videoFrame, 'Rectangle',bbox,'Color','green');

    number = size(bbox,1);

    result = insertText(result, [10 10], number, 'BoxOpacity', 1, 'FontSize', 14);

    step(videoPlayer, result);  % display the results
end

release(videoReader); % close the video fil
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use the `insertObjectAnnotation` function, which draws a bounding box together with a label into the image.